# while inside while runs just once

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a problem with this code, the thing is that the inner `while` just runs once while the outer `while` does it right. What could be the problem?

Note: `$producto_id` is an array with ids.

```
$st_column = 0;
$nd_column = 1;
$posicionArray = 0;

if (($handle = fopen($ruta, "r")) != FALSE) {
    fgetcsv($handle);
    mysqli_query($link, "BEGIN");
    while($producto_id[$posicionArray]){                        
        $ins_producto = mysqli_query ($link, "INSERT INTO productos (encuesta_id, producto_id, nom_producto) VALUES ('".$encuesta_id."', '".$producto_id[$posicionArray]."', '".$nombre_producto[$posicionArray]."')");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "$delimiter")) != FALSE) {                      
            if($producto_id[$posicionArray] == $data[$st_column]){                              
                $ins_cupon = mysqli_query ($link, "INSERT INTO cupones (encuesta_id, producto_id, cupon, estado) VALUES ('".$encuesta_id."', '".$producto_id[$posicionArray]."', '".$data[$nd_column]."', 0)");                 
            }                                                   
        }
        $posicionArray ++;
    }

    fclose($handle);                
}
```

Comment: wheres `$delimeter` set?

Comment: In a HTML form, Only ";" or "," allowed

Comment: can you show what `$producto_id` has? you say it an array of ids, but if the array is like this `[0,1,2]`, then your initial condition will fail because it will equal zero which will break the `while` loop

Comment: I save some ids in the array from an HTML form. Then I call the array like this:
$producto_id = $_POST['producto_id'];
It could have something like this [1,2,3, ...]

Comment: what is your second while loop trying to do? I believe `fgetcsv` only gets the first line in your csv, which would explain why you only loop once

Comment: instead of `while` you should use `foreach` to iterate through your `$producto_id` array. Its much simpler and you dont end up with that "not set" error in your last iteration.

Comment: Goes through the file and save the data only if the if condition it's true. Or that should do...

Comment: I'll try with foreach then

Comment: So from what I understand your goal is the following: you have a list of ids, and a csv file. You want to make sure that if the id (in your list) is in the csv line, then you add it to your database. Correct? if not can you explain in detail your goal?

Comment: Exactly but I can't delete the first while

Comment: Perhaps it would be best if you provide a sample of your csv file as well

Comment: id,cupon
1,15165165
1,16516151
2,16841684

it's a test csv

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you meant by:

($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "$delimiter")

if you meant:
($data == fgetcsv($handle, 0, "$delimiter"))
that is    the value of data is equal to the result of  fgetcsv
    then your code is wrong. and switch to "=="

if you mean:
($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "$delimiter"))
and fgetcsv  can return a "0"  then that is why.

using "assignments" in the middle of if statements is always bad practice.

if you do an assignment in the middle of your if statement, the value of the assignment is passed on to the boolean expression.  Any value other than 0 is considered true.   otherwise a 0 is considered false.

Comment: Ok, I've tried with "==" and doesn't run at all. So how could I fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: try doing the fgetcsv($handle, 0, "$delimiter")  before the if statement.  assign it to a variable and either debug or some sort of printout  to see the value of it.   and the value of  $data

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a csv, which holds ids and coupons. It seems you are trying to go through your `producto_id` array and check if that exists in your CSV. This is what I would do:

**CSV:**

```
id,cupon
1,15165165
1,16516151
2,16841684
```

**PHP:**

```
function turn_csv_to_array($csv) {
    $result = array();
    if (($h = fopen($csv, "r")) != FALSE) {
        $header = fgetcsv($h);
        while ($row = fgetcsv($h)) {
            $result[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($h);
    }
    return $result;
}

$coupons = turn_csv_to_array("test.csv");
$product_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];


foreach ($product_ids as $pid) {
    // INSERT PRODUCT TO PRODUCT_DB
    foreach ($coupons as $c) {
        if ($pid == $c['id']) {
            // INSERT PRODUCT TO COUPONS_DB
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a better way, but still the same problem. The inner foreach just runs once

Comment: I removed the `break` does that still happen?

Comment: Yes, it still happen

Comment: Then you are not explaining your problem correctly. Provide more information so that we can understand better.

Comment: The first foreach goes through all the array, but the second just goes throught the first value of the array cupones.

Comment: So what do you need it to do? Please be specific

Comment: I need that the second foreach also goes through all the values because I need to save all the values only if exists in $product_id array

Comment: the first foreach already goes through all the values found in the `product_ids` array. The second for each checks if that id exists in the CSV, if it does, it INSERTs it.. I really dont understand what you are trying to do now.

Comment: I have to insert all the values with that id, then go to the next value in the array and do the same